# code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

Tags: java, android, flutter, performance, kotlin

I am trying to make Bluetooth chatting app. I have two activities in it:
**please please see it is a short project**
git repo:https://github.com/soam1/BlueToothChattingApp.git 
1.MainActivity
2.DeviceListActivity 
Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.bluetoothchatapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager ;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        initBluetooth();
    }

    private void initBluetooth() {
//        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Bluetooth found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_search_devices) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "searching for devices...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checkPermissions();
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_enable_bluetooth) {
//            Toast.makeText(context, "Turning on Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            enableBluetooth();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    private  void checkPermissions(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setCancelable(false).setMessage("Please grant location permission(required)").setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        checkPermissions();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        }else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void enableBluetooth() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth already enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Turning on Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                // Permission has not been granted, so we need to request it
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Could not turn on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else{
                bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            }
        }
        if(bluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE){
            Intent discoveryIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoveryIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoveryIntent);
        }
    }




//    @Override
//    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
//        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
//        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION) {
//            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                Toast.makeText(context,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//            else {
//                Toast.makeText(context,"permission NOT granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        }
//    }


}
```

Here is my DeviceListActivity.java:

---

**error showing is:
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException**

```
package com.example.bluetoothchatapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.Set;

public class DeviceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listPairedDevices, listAvailableDevices;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPairedDevices;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAvailableDevices;
private  static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 101;
private Context context;


private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);
context = this;
init();
}

private void init() {
listAvailableDevices = findViewById(R.id.list_available_devices);
listPairedDevices = findViewById(R.id.list_paired_devices);

adapterAvailableDevices = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.device_list_item);
adapterPairedDevices = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.device_list_item);

listPairedDevices.setAdapter(adapterPairedDevices);
listPairedDevices.setAdapter(adapterAvailableDevices);
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices=null;
>! # //***here(below line)***
pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
if(pairedDevices!=null && pairedDevices.size()>0){
for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices){
>! # //***here(below line)***
adapterPairedDevices.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml:\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BluetoothChatApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please review the [ask] link and then consider sharing more pertinent information in your question.

Comment: Also, have you checked the answers that can be found in the many [similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+Call+requires+permission+which+may+be+rejected+by+user)?